# Linear gradient equation in the plane

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

Observe the following equation:

$V(y)=\frac{a}{2}y_1^2+\frac{b}{2}y_2^2+c y_1y_2$

a) Find the matrix $A$ which you find on the right hand side of the equation.

b) Calculate the Trace, determinant, eigenvalues and the discriminant $\Delta$ of the eigenvalue equation for $A$ in terms of $a,b,c$.

c) Use the new parameters $s=\frac{a+b}{\sqrt{2}},u=\frac{a-b}{\sqrt{2}} \text{and }  v=\sqrt{2}c$ and draw the surface $A=0$ in the $(s,u,v)$-space.

d)Give for the parameter values $(s,u,v)=(3,1,0),(1,1,0) \text{ and } (-3,1,0)$ their phase plot.

I don't know how to find the matrix. If I know the matrix I'm able to do question b, but thought it would be convenient to give the whole question. (There are also some question related to this one, I don't think it's necessary write them down. But if the question is unclear that might be the reason)